# Can Services implement the SensorEventListener

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service

Can I use the SensorEventListener with a service?

I want to do something when my application is running in background with a service being active. When a user shakes the phone I want a code to run in background.
So is it possible for services to detect shake changes??

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Because, I saw an application (Avast) in which there is an option like whenever we lost the phone, we can request the device to get the GPS location with out the permission of the user and will send it to us to the web. The webservice will activate the Android services in the mobile which will automatically activate the GPS with out the users interface and will send the location.

Comment: Thanks! :) .. i implemented a service with shake listener to listen for a start cmd!